# Ipad Error: 'Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS'

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I am getting this error when I deploy to my iPad. It does not occur in the simulator.

My ipad app has three UIWebViews. The majority of this application is written completely as a web app, and uses CSS to make it look more native. Links that are clicked in the various web views will open in a certain one depending on the value of the request variable "iPadTarget."

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

 //Extract the value from request variable 'iPadTarget' in url string.
 NSString *test = [url query];
 int index = [test rangeOfString:@"iPadTarget="].location; 
 int target = index + 11;
 NSLog(@"%i", target);
 char c = [test characterAtIndex:target];
 NSLog(@"%c",c);

 if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
  if (c == '1') {
      [viewOne loadRequest:request];
      return NO;
  } else if (c == '2') {
   [viewTwo loadRequest:request];
   return NO;
  } else if (c == '3') {
   [viewThree loadRequest:request];
   return NO;
  }
 } 
  return YES;
  [url release];
    }
```

The above code locates the variable "iPadTarget" and extracts its value (1 to 3). Why am I get this strange error? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
[url release];
```

is the source of your trouble.  You are releasing an object you do not own.  You acquired the url through the -URL method of the request, and as it does not contain `new`, `create`, or `copy` you are not the owner.  Remove the line `[url release]`, and re-read the memory management guidelines.